# Looking to get a particular value of a Json array in python

Tags: python, arrays, json, pandas

I am trying to parse particular values of a Json data set in python. For example:

```
"id": 1234,
      "title": "Product name",
      "handle": "product-name-handle",
      "body_html": "Product description",
      "vendor": "Vendor name",
      "product_type": "Type 1",
      "tags": [
        "category--type1",
        "width_max--1.000000",
        "length_max--2.000000",
        "language--en"
      ]""
```

Say I want to get the value of the "length_max" in that array. I know you can call the location [1] in this case, but the problem is that the next product might have "width_max" or some other field and the location might go from [1] to [2]. So I want to know how I can search for "width_max" and then trim to get just the value so I can help parse all the products confidentially. Can I use pandas for this? Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is overkill, this is basic json processing in python. Import the `json` module, parse your json data with `json.load` (from file) or `json.loads` (from string). You'll get a python dictionary that you can search. If you need help with that, see the python [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

you can do that like this.

```
jsonString = {"id": 1234,"title": "Product name","handle": "product-name-handle",
             "body_html": "Product description","vendor": "Vendor name",      
             "product_type": "Type 1","tags": ["category--type1","width_max--1.000000","length_max--2.000000","language--en"]}

def getValueFromJson(jsonString, key):
  tag = jsonString['tags']
  if isinstance(tag, list):
    for value in tag:
      if key in value:
        name, val = value.split('--')
        print(f'Key : {name} :: value : {val}')
    

getValueFromJson(jsonString, 'length_max')

OUTPUT : Key : length_max :: value : 2.000000
```

your json was not valid it was missing {} and had extra " at the end,
using above method you can get any key value from list.